# Elm 0.19: elm make "not enough bytes" error when compiling

Tags: elm

I am suddenly receiving this error message when compiling my app:

```
elm make  src/App.elm --output ../assets/javascripts/elm/App.js
elm: not enough bytes
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/binary/src/Data/Binary.hs:212:21 in binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary
make: *** [App.js] Error 1
```

Compiler bug?

Edit: The workaround is to delete elm-stuff. Then it will compile once, and have the same bug on the next attempt.

Comment: We will need the failing source code to start with... :)

Comment: It fixed itself after I fixed all the compiler errors in one particular file. I wish I had committed the broken state now.

Comment: In future, who should I send the source code to if I want to keep it private? Thanks!

Comment: @wmakley If you want to keep it private, you'll probably need to pay someone to advise you - StackOverflow is a public space for helping others and sharing knowledge, keeping it private doesn't really work with that.

Comment: @GarethLatty I know, it is just proprietary code and this is a compiler bug that I want to help fix. I assume the solution will eventually be "install a patch". I'm working on anonymizing it, but it is slow going.

Comment: So far I've only seen this error in the large app I work on professionally. Small side projects seem immune

Comment: I do have the same error after upgrading to 0.19 with a 5k lines application.

It does not seem linked to a particular error in the Elm code as long as there is one and the previous build also had an error.

Comment: We do have the same problem with our large codebase after upgrading to 0.19. Right now I'm doing `rm -rf elm-stuff && yarn start` to remove `elm-stuff` and start the build again. It is ok as the build is quite quick but still annoying :(